# How to change the clock speed with an Asus B350M mother board?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, overclocking

I am trying to change the clock speed from the BIOS on a Asus B350 with a Ryzen CPU. No matter how I change the custom CPU core ratio, if it isn't on Auto, the system won't boot.

The base settings are 3.5 GHz (35 x 100 MHz). The description of the fields is

> Custom CPU core ratio = 2 * FID / DID

How could the clock be kept at 3.5 GHz using the the manual FID (multiplier) and DID (divider)? The FID can range from 16 to 255 and the DID from 8 to 48.

Comment: It needs to be set on auto so that the CPU can manage itself and the fan. Why do you need a constant speed? That is generally not a good idea.

Comment: I want to underclock and use a passive cooler. The CPU is rated at 65W and the cooler is rated for 47W. It's why I wanted a customizable system. I will lover the CPU voltage by offset. Having a dynamically changing clock speed is less of a  danger because I won't be overclocking.